# MVC4 Add controller error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, ef-database-first

When I try to add a controller to my WebUI I get the following error:

```
'DTO.Games' is not part of the specified 'DAL.GamesEntities' class, and
the 'DAL.GamesEntities' class could not be modified to add a
'DbSet<DTO.Games>' property to it. (For example, the
'Dal.GamesEntities' class might be in a compiled assembly
```

I searched a before asking here but none of the solutions online helped me. I'm working DBFirst. Any code that could help solving this: ask and you shall receive.

Thanks in advance

CODE

- Games.Context.cs (contains GamesEntities) - http://pastebin.com/rL9U2eTp

Comment: Can you show your context class, I assume is `DAL.GameEntities`.

Comment: @Guillelon Added Games.Context.cs which contains GamesEntities

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using? The version 6 pre-release caused something similar in MVC4. If you're using EF6 you might need to upgrade to MVC5.

Comment: @melkisadek Version 5.0.0

Comment: `public DbSet<tblGames> tblGames { get; set; }` would suggest you need to be creating the controller from "tblGames" rather than "Games"

Comment: @melkisadek I get the following error: http://imgur.com/xkf7xV5

Comment: Can you post the code from your EDMX relating to the tblGames entity and the class for the same? Do you have any validation running against tblGames that might contain an extra property that isn't in the original class?

Comment: @melkisadek I solved the problem but couldn't answer my own question for X hours :P Anyways, there was a bunch of stuff I did wrong, a list too long to post, thx for the help!